# C: Turning ints into char* buffers?

Tags: c

I'm working on a strange little embedded platform that seems to have undefined behavior when calling their POSIX-compliance functions with source pointers that are anything other than a char*. It's kind of a stupid workaround, but how would I go about converting an int in C to a character buffer with the same bit ordering?

For example:

```
int foo = 15;
turning into
char* bar = "\x00\x0F\x00\x00";
```

Comment: what are the extra null bytes for?

Comment: Registers on this strange little platform are 32 bits wide, right?

Comment: Which Endianess is this?  Big Endian: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F; Little Endian: 0x0F 0x00 0x00 0x00.

Comment: Do you want to point to the value 15, or do you want address 15?  Your question is anything but clear.

Comment: EDIT: Wait, now I'm confused. Hang on a sec.

Comment: Well. The processor is nominally a PowerPC 604 running some ancient form of VxWorks, but 0x00 0x0F 0x00 0x00 isn't 15 on any PowerPC I've ever seen before. And yet it is. (And yes, I want it to point to the value 15)

Answer (score 5):

Use this method:

```
function((char *)&bar)
```

Comment: So it turns out I'm a bloody moron and the problem was something else entirely, but a cast is indeed the correct solution for anyone else who needs to do it.